# Add style to data that is set within case statement in sql query

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, case

I am looking to modify the color of each result in the Status column of my gridview, is there anyway to do this using the case statements in my query or will I have to change that?

Basically if it is Pending its red, if it is In Review its in orange, and if its Complete its green. What's the best way to accomplish this with the current code?

I'm doing everything in Visual Studio in C#.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Code behind SQL statement where I declare the status variables:

```
SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT W.ID, W.Name, 
                CASE W.Type
                    WHEN 1 then 'U.S.'
                    WHEN 2 then 'Foreign'
                end as Type,
                CASE W.Status
                    WHEN 0 then 'Pending'
                    WHEN 1 then 'In Review'
                    WHEN 2 then 'Complete'
                end as Status,
```

..etc

Front:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" CssClass="gridview" BorderColor="#E8CC6B"
        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="Medium" HorizontalAlign="Left"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even" Width="750px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            AllowPaging="True" onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
            PageSize="25" ShowFooter="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"> <PagerStyle CssClass="cssPager" /><FooterStyle CssClass="cssFooter" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
            </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event to achieve this. Set the Cells color on the basis of Text.

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      switch (e.Row.Cells[3].Text)
        {
            case "Panding":
                e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                break;
            case "Complete":
                e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                break;
            case "In Review":
                e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                break;
            default:
                e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                break;
        };

     }
  }
```

Comment: You my friend are a godsend! This is perfect, works great. Thank you for the quick and spot on reply!